# Why my accuracy plot for train and test is so weird?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am relatively new to neural network. I am trying to see the difference between loss and accuracy. However for accuracy plot, the train data and test data is not touching each other. Is this correct?

[image]  [image]

```
 #model compile
 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mse", metrics=['acc'])
 filepath = "Autopilot.h5"
 checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
 callbacks_list = [checkpoint]


 def main():
     features, labels = loadFromPickle()
     features, labels = shuffle(features, labels)
     train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(features, labels, random_state=0,
                                                    test_size=0.3)
     train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], 100, 100, 1)
     test_x = test_x.reshape(test_x.shape[0], 100, 100, 1)
     model, callbacks_list = keras_model(100, 100)
     history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(test_x, test_y), epochs=30, 
     batch_size=32, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

What should i change in this?

Comment: What is the task here? And the data/architecture?

Comment: It is training the steering angle from a .txt file

Comment: That sounds like regression, where accuracy is not a valid metric.

Comment: so it is not possible to get the accuracy?

Comment: It would make no sense, as accuracy is a classification metric, not applicable to regression (continuous values)

Comment: ok thanks this is what i was looking for as i m very new to this. Sorry for this kind of question

Answer (score 1):

Here is some general information.

Yes, your testing percentage will generally always be worse than your training percentage.  When you first initialize the network, both your testing and training percentage should be horrible, with both getting better over time.   After some number of epochs, your model will start to 'over-train', meaning it decides based on individual small details of your training data and starts doing worse on your testing data.

In the graphs you give, your Epoch vs Loss function graph looks correct, but the Model Accuracy graph looks like you are not graphing what you think you are graphing.

I find I spend a large portion of my neural network time just trying to keep hold of what's going on.  It's not just you. :)

Have a great day!

Answer (score -2):

Hard to say what is going on without knowing the data. In a nutshell your model seems to learn, but this learning does not result in an improvement of accuracy. This is well possible. It is not necessarily the case that train/test accuracy touches each other.

What can you do: tune your model and make sure that it learns in a proper way. Try on the capacity of the model, change batch size, maybe add regularization. Also see what happens if you train for more epochs.

Note: if you have a small(ish) amount of data, neural nets do not perform too good. In this case you would need to resort to some other method, maybe boosting.